# images not inserting into new posts for some reason

Tags: css, wordpress

So im unable to insert media into new posts, and the featured image is not showing up either. Every other post has had images show up fine. I have googled everywhere trying to find a solution but cannot. I am also not sure what relevant code i could show you guys. Honestly not sure how this could be happening.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting? any error messages while posting?

Comment: no error, it just acts like a normal insert, except after selecting file the body of text remains blank. my media library is not populating old or storing new uploads.

Comment: you mean you can upload the images to wordpress but you cant render it to the front page or some page?

Comment: http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/ <- every post on that main page has a working featured image and other images added. the lastest post only has thumbnail and theres nothing inside. i made every post the same way.

Comment: can you paste your code of that page?

Comment: you mean just viewsource?

Comment: you mean my style sheet?

Comment: lol ur wordpress code

Comment: im sorry, do you mean my custom css?